# Find indices in a 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, find, matrix-indexing

I have 2 3D matrices:

```
A=[19,18,17;16,15,14;13,12,11];

A(:,:,2)=[9,8,7;6,5,4;3,2,1];

B=sort(A,3);
```

With output

```
A(:,:,1) =


19 18 17

16 15 14

13 12 11


A(:,:,2) =


9 8 7

6 5 4

3 2 1


B(:,:,1) =


9 8 7

6 5 4

3 2 1


B(:,:,2) =


19 18 17

16 15 14

13 12 11
```

and I want to find the 3rd coordinate of one of the matrices of `B` in `A`.

so

```
find(A==B(:,:,1))
```

the answer is

```
ans =



10

11

12

13

14

15

16

17

18
```

However, I want the answer to be `2`, because this matrix is in the second position in the third dimension of `A`: `A(:,:,2)`

How do I do this?

I tried `find(A(~,~,:)==B(:,:,1))` but that gave an error.

Comment: why the secondary output of the sort function, the indices, are not what you are looking for?

Comment: @GideonKogan if you do ´[x,y,z]=find(A==B(:,:,1))´ y=[4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6] which you cant fill into A because that always has a max of 3 (A(1,4,1) is impossible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ind2sub`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) to convert linear indices (which `find()` gives you) to indices per dimension:

```
A=[19,18,17;16,15,14;13,12,11];

A(:,:,2)=[9,8,7;6,5,4;3,2,1];

B=sort(A,3);

lin_idx = find(A==B(:,:,1));

[row,col,page] = ind2sub(size(A),lin_idx);  % page is 2 everywhere
```

I recommend reading [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32379805/5211833) for more information on the different types of indexing which MATLAB supports.