# How to read data correctly in Matlab

Tags: matlab, complex-numbers

I Have a .bin file with data in little-endian format 16 bit.
When I use

```
[Signal,count]=fread(fid,960000,'int16','l');
```

I get only integer data:

```
255
-1234
9455
25465
-3546
-6878
```

How to read this data to get them in complex form? I need to get:

```
255 - 1234i
9455 + 25465i
-3546 - 6878i
```

Answer (score 2):

Presuming you have these integers in `Signal`:

```
complex_signal = Signal(1:2:end)+1i*Signal(2:2:end)
```

with [indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32379805/5211833)! The idea is that your real and imaginary parts are interlaced, i.e. the odd indices, `1:2:end`, contain the real part, and the even indices, `2:2:end`, the imaginary part. Simply add the two with a factor `1i` to get complex numbers.