# Indexing a matrix in matlab according to conditions set on other matrices

Tags: matlab

I am trying to index my matrix based on two conditions, I'll explain.

Let's say I have two matrices:

```
a = [7 3 4; 5 6 7; 4 8 0];
b = [1 9 8; 2 4 6; 6 1 6];
```

And a third matrix to index:

```
c = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
```

My aim is to index c in a way that I get a 3x3 matrix in which only the values of c are copied over for whose indexes the following conditions are met and the rest are zeros.

```
a <= 5, b >= 6
```

Resulting matrix:

```
result = [0 2 3; 0 0 0; 7 0 9]
```

I hope I was able to explain my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
a = [7 3 4; 5 6 7; 4 8 0];
b = [1 9 8; 2 4 6; 6 1 6];
c = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
result = zeros(size(c);
```

Using logical indexing,

```
>> d = (a <= 5) & (b >= 6)
d =
  0  1  1
  0  0  0
  1  0  1

>> result(d) = c(d)
result =
   0   2   3
   0   0   0
   7   0   9
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Comment: @NikitParakh You might be interested in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that).

Answer (score 0):

Loop throw rows and columns and set the result.

```
for row=1:size(a,1)
    for col=1:size(a,2)
          if(a(row,col)> b(row,col))
              result(row,col) = 0
          else
               result(row,col) = c(row,col)
          end  
    end
end
```

Comment: What if the conditions are a<=3, b>=8?

Comment: And is there a way to do this without loops? Because this may work for smaller matrices, but with larger ones, it may take a lot of time.

Comment: MATLAB doesn't run in JavaScript snippets. It would be better to use normal code formatting.

Comment: If you are going to use a loop, you should at least preallocate `result` to avoid slowing down due to memory reallocation