# MATLAB MATRIX cell index in integer format, not row and column format

Tags: matlab, matrix

In the MATLAB, a matrix cell is numbered by its row and column position. I wanted to index by the integer number.

Consider a (3,4) matrix

```
for i=1:length(3)
  for j =1:length(4)
    fprint(i,j)
  end
end
1,1
1,2
.
.
3,4
```

However, the output I am expecting when iterating through each cell is given by

```
for i=1:length(3)
  for j =1:length(4)
    fprint(i+j+something)
  end
end
1
2
3
4
.
.
12
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linear indexing, logical indexing, and all that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called *linear indexing*. You can use the function [`sub2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to convert from row and column number to linear index, and [`ind2sub`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) to go the other way.

```
index = sub2ind(size(M),i,j);
M(i,j) == M(index)
```

The formula applied by `sub2ind` for a 2D matrix is `index = i + (j-1) * size(M,1)`. That is, numbers increase downward along the first column, then the second column, etc.

Comment: I have question. A simple code is troubling me a lot. Here is my code: `for i=1:length(3) 
   for j=1:length(3) 
       n = sub2ind(size(Rld),i,j);
       fprintf('%i\n',n)
   end     
end ` For unknown reasons , it prints only `1`, not `1..9`. Any idea what could be wrong here.

Comment: @Mainland: `length(3)` is 1. You want to do `for i=1:3`.

Comment: oho.. i got it now. This is a simple yet big mistake. THanks a ton.

Comment: The index is actually set to `index = i + (j - 1) * size(M,1)`

Comment: @JorenV: Thanks for pointing out the typo.