# Convert dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss to seconds using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, date

I work with csv and must subtract 2 cells with the following date format `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss`. I need to extract only the seconds.

`Timestamp` is a column and I attempted:

```
data1 = Timestamp(1) ;
data2 =  Timstamp(2) ; % returns error
class(data1); % returns cell 
data1 - data2 % returns error
```

How can I convert the cells into a number which I can subtract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [index into your cell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32379805/5211833) to extract the date string. Then you can use [`datenum`](https://4athworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) to convert it to "decimal days since 1st January 0000". Then it's a simple matter of subtracting your starting date (convert that using `datenum` as well) and changing from decimal days to seconds:

```
tmp = your_cell{1}; % e.g. 26.11.2020 00:00:00, is a string
tmp_date = datenum(tmp); % MATLAB datenum, decimal days.
tmp_date2 = datenum(your_cell{2});
no_start = tmp_date2-tmp_date;  % remove starting date
time_sec = no_start*(24*60*60);  % change decimal days to seconds
```

Or as a oneliner:

```matlab
(datenum(your_cell{2})-datenum(your_cell{1}))*(24*60*60)
```