# How to create all permutations of a 2-column cell-array?

Tags: matlab, permutation, cell-array, cartesian-product

I created a cell array of shape `m x 2`, each element of which is a matrix of shape `d x d`.

For example like this:

```matlab
A = cell(8, 2);
for row = 1:8
    for col = 1:2
        A{row, col} = rand(3, 3);
    end
end
```

More generally, I can represent `A` as follows:

[image]

where each `A_{ij}` is a matrix.

Now, I need to randomly pick a matrix from each row of `A`, because `A` has `m` rows in total, so eventually I will pick out m matrices, which we call a **combination**.

Obviously, since there are only two picks for each row, there are a total of **2^m** possible combinations.

My question is, how to get these **2^m** combinations quickly?

---

It can be seen that the above problem is actually finding the Cartesian product of the following sets:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`2^m` is actually a binary number, so we can use those to create linear indices. You'll get an array containing 1s and 0s, something like `[1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1]`, which we can treat as column "indices", using a `0` to indicate the first column and a `1` to indicate the second.

```matlab
m = size(A, 1);
% Build all binary numbers and create a logical matrix
bin_idx = dec2bin(0:(2^m -1)) == '1';

row = 3;  % Loop here over size(bin_idx,1) for all possible permutations
linear_idx = [find(~bin_idx(row,:)) find(bin_idx(row,:))+m];
A{linear_idx}  % the combination as specified by the permutation in out(row)
```

On my R2007b version this runs virtually instant for `m = 20`.

NB: this will take `m * 2^m` bytes of memory to store `bin_idx`. Where that's just 20 MB for `m = 20`, that's already 30 GB for `m = 30`, i.e. you'll be running out of memory fairly quickly, and that's for just storing permutations as booleans! If `m` is large in your case, you can't store all of your possibilities anyway, so I'd just select a random one:

```matlab
bin_idx = rand(m, 1);  % Generate m random numbers
bin_idx(bin_idx > 0.5) = 1;  % Set half to 1
bin_idx(bin_idx < 0.5) = 0;  % and half to 0
```

---

Old, slow answer for large `m`

[`perms()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/perms.html)<sup>1</sup> gives you all possible permutations of a given set. However, it does not take duplicate entries into account, so you'll need to call [`unique()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to get the unique rows.

```matlab
unique(perms([1,1,2,2]), 'rows')

ans =

     1     1     2     2
     1     2     1     2
     1     2     2     1
     2     1     1     2
     2     1     2     1
     2     2     1     1
```

The only thing left now is to somehow do this over all possible amounts of `1`s and `2`s. I suggest using a simple loop:

```matlab
m = 5;
out = [];

for ii = 1:m
    my_tmp = ones(m,1);
    my_tmp(ii:end) = 2;
    out = [out; unique(perms(my_tmp),'rows')];
end

out = [out; ones(1,m)];  % Tack on the missing all-ones row

out =
     2     2     2     2     2
     1     2     2     2     2
     2     1     2     2     2
     2     2     1     2     2
     2     2     2     1     2
     2     2     2     2     1
     1     1     2     2     2
     1     2     1     2     2
     1     2     2     1     2
     1     2     2     2     1
     2     1     1     2     2
     2     1     2     1     2
     2     1     2     2     1
     2     2     1     1     2
     2     2     1     2     1
     2     2     2     1     1
     1     1     1     2     2
     1     1     2     1     2
     1     1     2     2     1
     1     2     1     1     2
     1     2     1     2     1
     1     2     2     1     1
     2     1     1     1     2
     2     1     1     2     1
     2     1     2     1     1
     2     2     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     2
     1     1     1     2     1
     1     1     2     1     1
     1     2     1     1     1
     2     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1
```

NB: I've not initialised `out`, which will be slow especially for large `m`. Of course `out = zeros(2^m, m)` will be its final size, but you'll need to juggle the indices within the `for` loop to account for the changing sizes of the unique permutations.

You can create [linear indices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32379805/5211833) from `out` using [`find()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html)

```matlab
linear_idx = [find(out(row,:)==1);find(out(row,:)==2)+size(A,1)];
A{linear_idx}  % the combination as specified by the permutation in out(row)
```

Linear indices are row-major in MATLAB, thus whenever you need the matrix in column 1, simply use its row number and whenever you need the second column, use the row number + `size(A,1)`, i.e. the total number of rows.

Combining everything together:

```matlab
A = cell(8, 2);
for row = 1:8
    for col = 1:2
        A{row, col} = rand(3, 3);
    end
end

m = size(A,1);
out = [];

for ii = 1:m
    my_tmp = ones(m,1);
    my_tmp(ii:end) = 2;
    out = [out; unique(perms(my_tmp),'rows')];
end

out = [out; ones(1,m)];

row = 3;  % Loop here over size(out,1) for all possible permutations
linear_idx = [find(out(row,:)==1).';find(out(row,:)==2).'+m];
A{linear_idx}  % the combination as specified by the permutation in out(row)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> There's a note in the documentation:

> `perms(v)` is practical when `length(v)` is less than about `10`.