# How to find minimum of each column in MATLAB and sum op all elements of that column?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 300x178 matrix and I want to find the minimum of each column of that matrix, i.e. resulting in a 1x178 array. Then I want to store the sum of all elements but the minimum in each column in the 300x178 matrix on the location/pixel of the minimum value, leaving all other elements zero. How can I do this using MATLAB?

Example:

```
1 4 6 3
2 6 7 4
5 1 5 7
```

becomes:

```
1 0 0 1
0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0
```

and eventually:

```
8  0  0 14
0  0  0 0
0 11 18 0
```

Comment: Your example and the text of your question do not correspond, see my answer. Both have a similar solution though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example and title do not correspond to the question text. Your example sums **all** values in a column and stores them at the location of the minimum, which the title also asks. You can do this by making smart use of [`sub2ind`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html):

```
A = [1 4 6 3
2 6 7 4
5 1 5 7];
C = zeros(size(A));
[tmp, idx] = min(A);  % find the locations of minima
% one liner to store the sum of columns
C(sub2ind(size(A), idx, 1:size(A,2))) = sum(A,1);
C =

     8     0     0    14
     0     0     0     0
     0    11    18     0
```

If, on the other hand, you're after what your question *text* asks about, subsequently subtract `A` on the minimum locations using the same `sub2ind` trick:

```
C(sub2ind(size(A), idx, 1:size(A,2))) = C(sub2ind(size(A), idx, 1:size(A,2))) - A(sub2ind(size(A), idx, 1:size(A,2)))

C =

     7     0     0    11
     0     0     0     0
     0    10    13     0
```

This way you get the sum of all elements **but** the minimum.

---

For an in-depth explanation what `sub2ind` does, read [this fantastic Q/A by Luis Mendo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32379805/5211833) keeping in mind that in `A(2,3)` the `2` and `3` are called *subscripts*, which, in case of a 3-by-4 matrix, translates to *linear index* `8`.

I cannot test this on my R2007b, but according to [the documentation on `min`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) you could use `[M, I] = min(A, [], 1, 'linear')` to get the linear indices into `I` directly, without going through `sub2ind`:

```
C = zeros(size(A));
[tmp, idx] = min(A, [], 1, 'linear');
C(idx) = sum(A, 1);
% Optional, to sum all but the minimum
C(idx) = C(idx) - A(idx);
```

Small note from the documentation on the occurrence of multiple same-valued minima in your original matrix:

> If the smallest element occurs more than once, then I contains the index to the first occurrence of the value.