# MATLAB - Changing color of a portion of an image by applying a mask

Tags: image, matlab, colors, object-detection, mask

I've got this coloured image and I obtained the following mask by doing object detection. I would like to apply this mask to the original image to change the color of the solids to the one that I like (or apply any effect to them, it doesn't really matter). I'm having trouble doing that.

I've tried creating a function that iterates over every pixel of the original image comparing it to the mask but it's not an efficient solution.

The mask is of *logical* type while the image is *uint8*

[image][image]

Comment: You would use logical indexing. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugly images below, but hopefully also an instructive example:

```
% Create dummy image
x = 0:4:255;

origimage = uint8(repmat(x,64,1));
origimage(:,:,2) = 100;
origimage(:,:,3) = 100;

% create dummy mask
colormask = logical(zeros(64,64));
colormask(1:20,30:50) = 1;

% display original image and mask

figure(1);image(origimage);
figure(2); imagesc(colormask);


% create altered image

newimage = origimage;
newimage(colormask) = 255; %changes first channel to 255 in masked pixels
figure(3); image(newimage);
```

[image: Example of altering image in a mask region]

Since colormask is a logical, you can use it directly to select the relevant pixels in the original image and modify them in one command.  Hope this helps.

**Added 7/12/2023 in response to comment about changing other channels:

You have flexibility to change the other channels.  My original code only changed the red channel because my mask was only 2D.

```
% change all three channels together

colormask2 = logical(zeros(64,64,3));
colormask2(1:20,30:50,1:3) = 1;

newimage2 = origimage;
newimage2(colormask2) = 200;
```

Alternate and more flexible approach:

```
%create 3D mask with different numbers for each channel
colormask3 = uint8(zeros(64,64,3));
colormask3(1:20,30:50,1) = 1;
colormask3(1:20,30:50,2) = 2;
colormask3(1:20,30:50,3) = 3;
        
newimage4 = origimage;
newimage4(logical(colormask3)) = 200; %gives same image as prior example
figure(4); image(newimage4);
        
newimage5 = origimage;
newimage5 = newimage5 + 10*colormask3; %adds 10 to red, 20 to green, 30 to blue
figure(5); image(newimage5);
        
%  add to the original image itself *1/2 for red, *1 for green, and *1.5
%  for blue
newimage6 = origimage + origimage.*colormask3/2;
figure(6); image(newimage6);
```

Comment: Thank you, Do you know how I would be able to change the green and blue channels? Can I use the mask to add any other effects?