# Replace the coordinate (0,0) with (10^-5 , 10^-5)

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I have a question about Matlab dealing with the replacement of the coordinate (0,0). I know that if I plug in the value (0,0) into `fx` and `fy` respectively, there will be errors. So what are the syntaxes available to solve this problem of replacing (0,0) with (10^-5,10^-5)?

The details of this problem are below:

[image: Question prompt]

My code:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(-5:0.1:5,-5:0.1:5);
z =  exp(-x.^2-y.^2)
figure(1),surf(x,y,z)

fx =((x)./(x.^2+y.^2)^0.5);
fy =((y)./(x.^2+y.^2)^0.5);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
x0 = 0;  % desired location to be found in x
y0 = 0;  % desired location to be found in y
tol = 1e-5  % Numerical tolerance

% Create a mask for points within the tolerance distance on both x and y
mask = (abs(x - x0) < tol ) & (abs(y - y0) < tol );

new_coord = 1e-5; % New coordinate

% Replace found locations
x(mask) = new_coord;
y(mask) = new_coord;
```

I've used numerical tolerance to search for the locations, as using a direct comparison might result in no locations matching. See [Why is 24.0000 not equal to 24.0000 in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/686439/5211833) for reference. Afterwards it's a simple trick of [logical indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32379805/5211833) to replace the found values.