# Replace -inf by min and +inf by max value in matlab array

Tags: arrays, matlab

An array having multiple infinite values as `+inf` and `-inf`. How to replace `-inf` by minimum value present in that array and `+inf` by maximum value of the same array. The array is an output of some calculation so it is unknown to us initially. However, just an example take an array as `A=[inf, 1, 2, inf, 0, -4, -inf, -1, -inf]`. Here min and max are clearly given as -4 and 2 and I can replace it easily using looping. How to do it for the resultant array of some calculation. I Will be thankful for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Matlab has a great capacity called logical indexing. It means that you can index your array with a Boolean array of the same length.

```
A=[inf, 1, 2, inf, 0, -4, -inf, -1, -inf]

%Replace the values where A==-inf with the minimum real number.
A(A==-inf) = min(A(isfinite(A)));
%Replace the values where A==+inf with the maximum real number.
A(A==inf)  = max(A(isfinite(A)));
```

Comment: ... or even of _different_ length :-) (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710299/corner-cases-unexpected-and-unusual-matlab/2462898#2462898), edit 3)